# Draw graph of function in R?

Tags: r

In R, is there a way to draw the graph of a function? For example

```
h(x) =  x^5 + x^8 + (cos(x))^3 + 0.6e^x
```

I have tried, but keep receiving syntax errors such as unexpected ^ in h(x)

Comment: `plot(x^5 + x^8 + (cos(x))^3 + 0.6*exp(x), type="l")`? Note that `0.6e^x` should be `0.6*exp(x)`

Comment: Or maybe OP is looking for something like `plot(function(x) x^5 + x^8 + (cos(x))^3 + 0.6*exp(x), -10, 10, type="l")`

Comment: or `curve(x^5 + x^8 + (cos(x))^3 + 0.6*exp(x))`

Comment: You definitely want `curve` as @BenBolker suggests.

Comment: well, `plot.function()` calls `curve()`, so my comment/answer and @Jilber's are almost-if-not-entirely identical.

Comment: @BenBolker But, Jilber's requires defining `x` first, whereas yours does not, at least as I attempt to run it.

Comment: You're right.  It's @MatthewPlourde's answer that is almost equivalent to mine.

Comment: +1. I never knew this was possible in R, and had always used Jilber's approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
h <- function(x) x^5 + x^8 + cos(x)^3 + .6*exp(x)

plot(1:10, h(1:10))

plot(1:10, h(1:10), pch=19, cex=3, col=rainbow(10, alpha=.5, .5), type='o', lty=2, ylab='', xlab='', main='Plots for da winnnn!')
```

[image]